# Chart controls for Bot framework using node.js

Tags: node.js, charts, botframework

I'm trying to display a pie chart in bot emulator using node js and microsoft bot framework .but couldn't find any relevant samples online , Do we really have a provision to display chart control in Bot framework using nodejs.

Thanks in advance for you'lls help..

Comment: Are you using .NET or Node SDK for BotBuilder? Interactive HTML charts are not currently supported. You would need to render/snapshot your chart as an image and send the image file as an attachment of your bot message.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @NilsW , That helps . so i would need to surf for how to render the chart as static image with BotBuilder. Im using Node SDK for Builder . I would really appreciate if you could share any sample meanwhile ....Thanks again ..

Comment: You wouldn't use BotBuilder SDK to do this. You would need to use a NPM module to create the chart and render it to a file, then send the image file as a message attachment. For example, check out [nchart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nchart) or [vega](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vega) modules.

Comment: That works ..Thanks Nils W..